# Flask-Session: redis vs filesystem

Tags: python, flask, redis, flask-session

In [Flask-Session](https://flask-session.readthedocs.io/) there are five different session types. I want to use `redis` but I have to install it first which may not be possible in a shared host. So I decided to use `filesystem` as the session type which uses `cachelib.file.FileSystemCache` as a session backend. Now my question is what are the cons of using `filesystem` instead of `redis`? Are the operations still atomic when using `filesystem`?

Comment: Typically only one process can write to a file at a given time, so problems around atomicity should be mitigated somewhat. Lower performance is the largest downside to using the filesystem. With shared hosting you also want to ensure the files are not readable by other users. Generally, file system store is ok for lower traffic use cases, especially if the session data is not frequently updated.